# cmake can't find Python.h in conda environment

Tags: cmake

I already installed Python-dev and I can track Python.h but I don't know why cmake can't find it.

```bash
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── example.h
├── example.i
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── runme.py
```

So I can compile with the following commands without cmake:

```bash
swig -c++ -python -shadow   example.i 
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c  example_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python3.8 
g++ -shared  example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

I have the following CMakeLists

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(example)
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(Python 3.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -fPIC")

set_source_files_properties(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
swig_add_library(example LANGUAGE python SOURCES example.i)
swig_link_libraries(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_target(python DEPENDS _example.so)
```

output:

```bash
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found SWIG: /usr/bin/swig4.0 (found version "4.0.1") 
-- Found Python: /home/ziaee/anaconda3/envs/hbt/lib/libpython3.8.so (found suitable version "3.8", minimum required is "3.8") found components: Development 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so (found version "3.9.16") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ziaee/git/workshops/cmake_tutorial/intro/02_demo/build
Scanning dependencies of target example_swig_compilation
[ 33%] Swig compile example.i for python
[ 33%] Built target example_swig_compilation
Scanning dependencies of target example
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example.dir/CMakeFiles/example.dir/examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/home/ziaee/git/workshops/cmake_tutorial/intro/02_demo/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx:2784:10: fatal error: example.h: No such file or directory
 2784 | #include "example.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/example.dir/CMakeFiles/example.dir/examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:132: CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I can also track `Python.h` in `/home/ziaee/anaconda3/envs/hbt/include/python3.8`.

`cmake version 3.16.3`.

Do you have any idea?